# Insert SQL error and Null cString error in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a final project iOS app for searching lyrics, and when you login in your account you can add favorite lyrics.

I'm getting error in connection manager in insertFav 
and getAllFav; the output is

> An exception occurred: *** `+[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString`

Here's my insertFav method:

```
-(void)insertFav:(Favorite*)favssssdsd{

    fileMgrs = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;

    NSString *sqlQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT or REPLACE INTO fav (username,title,artist,image,song) VALUES ('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@');",favssssdsd.username,favssssdsd.lirikTitle,favssssdsd.lirikArtist,favssssdsd.lirikImage,favssssdsd.lirikSong];
    NSLog(@"query:%@",sqlQuery);
    const char *sql =[sqlQuery cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //NSLog(@"row:%d",row);
    //Open db
    NSString *cruddatabase = [self.GetCacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TB.sqlite"];
    sqlite3_open([cruddatabase UTF8String], &db);
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);

    if(sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
    {

    }

    else{
        NSLog(@"ERROR");
        // NSLog(@"name:%@",trip.poi_name);
    }

    sqlite3_reset(stmt);

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

And here is my GetAllFav method:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)GetAllFav :(NSString *)username{

    NSMutableArray *arrayItems=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    @try {
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *dbPath = [self.GetCacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TB.sqlite"];
        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        if(!success)
        {
            [self CopyDbToCachesFolder];
            [self GetAllFav:username];
            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
        }
        if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"An error has occured.");
        }

        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM fav where username='%@'",username];
        //SELECT * FROM artist where artist_name = 'Taylor Swift';
        const char *sql = [query UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement");
        }
        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

            Favorite *lyricyey = [[Favorite alloc]init];

            lyricyey.username =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0)];
            lyricyey.lirikTitle =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 1)];
            lyricyey.lirikArtist =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 2)];
            lyricyey.lirikImage =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 3)];
            lyricyey.lirikSong =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 4)];
            lyricyey.lirik =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 5)];


            [arrayItems addObject:lyricyey];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
    }
    @finally {
        return arrayItems;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `sqlite3_column_text` can return `NULL` for any column that allows for `NULL` values in the database. The error happens when you try to pass this `NULL` value to the `stringWithUTF8String:` method of `NSString`.

You need to update your code to handle these possible cases. For example:

Update the line:

```
lyricyey.username =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0)];
```

to:

```
char *str = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0);
lyricyey.username = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str ? str : ""];
```

where it is assumed you want the empty string for the property if the database has no value for the column.

Answer (score -1):

You are allowing nil values in your databas during insert?

If yes, you need to check every line for nil returning value

```
//this line
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0)]
```

one alternative solution is using:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0)];
// which will return `(null)` by default if the returning values is in type NULL
//
// or maybe
char *sql = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0)
[NSString stringWithUTF8String: sql == NULL ? "(null)" : sql];
// will do.
```

instead of the one you have there, so your code will look like:

```
lyricyey.username = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0)];

// or 
char *sql = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0)
lyricyey.username = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (sql == NULL) ? "(null)" : sql];

// or the direct approach
lyricyey.username = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (((char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0)) == NULL) ? "(null)" : sql];
```

---

while under `insertFav` i have no idea what causing you the error.

I made a customized class for database handling, but it is using `<sqlite3.h>` i dont think you have the same?

Hope this is useful to you.. And good luck with your final project.. ;) Cheers!

Comment: None of these solutions will work. None of them handle the case where `sqlite3_column_text` returns `NULL`.

Comment: @rmaddy, did you try it sir?

Comment: Try what? You didn't post any code that checks for `NULL` values.

Comment: @rmaddy, my answer is `you need to check every line for nil value`, i want to help not to spoon feed him. i just gave him clues.. hmm. sorry im just 47days old here in stackoverflow, i should have made my answer more clearer.. i'll edit my answer..

Comment: The problem with your answer is that you offer alternative "solutions" that won't actually work. Using `initWithUTF8String:` will result in the same crash if `NULL` is used. And using `stringWithFormat:` will give you the string `(null)` if given a value of `NULL`.

Comment: @rmaddy, yes i can see that, again i'm sorry.. i'm editing it.. :)